# C program that executes command fails with sleep

Tags: c, sleep, execve

I wrote a program that read a bash file line by line and execute its command written inside.

It seems to execute standard command normally (albeit there is not output on the terminal), but when it reads the sleep command, there is an error:

```
sleep 3: missing operand
Try 'sleep 3 --help' for more information.
```

```
char** string_separator(char* string, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp       = string;
    char* last_dot = 0;
    char delimiter[2];
    delimiter[0] = a_delim;
    delimiter[1] = 0;


    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_dot = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    count += last_dot < (string + strlen(string) - 1);
    count++;
    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(string,delimiter);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delimiter);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
  char buf[100];
  int bytes_read = 0;
  char * inputCopy = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
  const char delim[] = " ";

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {

    if (strstr(buffer, "#!/")) {

    } else {
      char ** strtoken = string_separator(buf, '\n');
      char * firstWord = getFirstWord(buf, inputCopy, delim);
      pid_t pid;
      pid = fork();

      if (pid == 0) {
        execvpe(firstWord, strtoken, NULL);
        exit(1);
      } else {

        int status;
        waitpid(pid, & status, 0);
      }

    }
  }
}

return 0;

}
```

Why is the program not working with the `sleep` command?

EDIT: Made the modification in the code such as function definition and indentation, I think the problem might be with the string_separator function, it might not separate the string into char array as expected.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Are you running the command `[ "sleep", "3" ]` or `[ "sleep 3" ]`? If you're looking for `"/usr/bin/sleep 3"` that's not a thing. The argument needs to be separated. It would help if you introduced some debugging code before your `exec` to see what args you're passing.

Comment: `getFirstWord()` or `string_separator()` are functions that are not defined in this post.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Tip: Collapse your definitions. `pid_t pid = fork()` not only saves a line, it makes it more concise and understandable.

Comment: And `*(result + idx++) = strdup(token);` is much clearer as `result[idx]=strdup(token);` then `idx++;` on the next line.  You gain nothing by cramming operations into one line - other than harder-to-read code.